# Developing asp.net application, use Google maps or bing maps?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, google-maps, bing-maps

I need to use a map in an application that I develop. In my application I want to use pins that will show infoboxes on the map. Use the zoom in, zoom out functionality and the ability to show several maps on the same page. I won't need to use the search locations or routing directions.

Which type of maps should I use? Google or Bing? As I understand, they both have good user interface, but which one is easier to develop with? If I'll use Bing then will it be more Microsoft like, I mean, it will let me use visual studio convenient programming? More or less javascript so it will be a hassle do debug it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In truth it doesn't matter.  They'll both get you the same results.  What you need to look as it the licensing agreements between the two of them.  That is going to be your real deciding factor.

Personally, I like Bing better, but that is entirely my opinion.  People who are really good with Google will tell you it is easier.  It all depends on what you are used to and what you like.  I would quickly mock up both and see which is better for you.

I would check [here](http://hnaser.blogspot.com/2009/07/google-maps-vs-bing-maps.html).  It is a comparison between the two and the writer's breakdown of what he experienced.

[Bing Maps Example](http://www.microsoft.com/maps/isdk/ajax/)
[Drawing a Circle in Bing Maps](http://soulsolutions.com.au/Blog/tabid/73/EntryId/612/Drawing-a-circle-in-Bing-Maps.aspx)

Sorry I don't have examples of Google's.  I haven't used it a while.

Comment: From what I saw, you can get both services keys for free. I already have the keys. The result will be the same. The question is how much hassle will be to get to the result by developing it? I thought in first that google maps is more trustworthy but then again, I like developing using visual studio and its much easier for me to develop using microsoft's controls. Are there any convenient controls using bing? Or its all done using javascript?

Comment: You can get both keys for free, but if you read the fine print there are restrictions on what you can use it for.  It has to be publicly available, set number of transactions a year etc.  In my opinion Bing was much easier to use, but I was checking out Silverlight etc.

Answer (score 1):

From a capability or customizability perspective, any of the options will meet your needs.

In terms of user experience, my personal preference is the Silverlight version of Bing Maps - very fast and smooth.  That does require Silverlight though which may or may not be acceptable to you.  If it's not, Google's AJAX map is 2nd best.  I find the AJAX version of Bing Maps to not be very fast or smooth when zooming or panning.